# Flappy Bird Game I am getting error while adding pipe

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I'm working for a flappy bird game.
I added the bird, tested it and there is no problem.
but when I test when adding pipes, I encounter such an error.
It gives an error on line 76. I could not solve this error.
Since my Java coding is not very good, I searched a lot for the error but couldn't find it. That's why I felt the need to open a topic here. I would be very happy if those who have knowledge can review and give information about the problem.

GameView.java

```js
package com.woxiapps.hopbird;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class GameView extends View {
    private Bird bird;
    private android.os.Handler handler;
    private Runnable r;
    private ArrayList<Pipe> arrPipes;
    private int sumpipe, distance;


    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initBird();
        initPipe();
        handler = new Handler();
        r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                invalidate();
            }
        };
    }

    private void initPipe() {
        sumpipe = 6;
        distance = 300*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/1920;
        arrPipes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sumpipe/2; i++){
            if (i < sumpipe/2) {
                this.arrPipes.add(new Pipe(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH+i*((Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH+200*Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/1080)/(sumpipe/2)),
                        0,200*Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/1080, Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2));
                this.arrPipes.get(this.arrPipes.size()-1).setBm(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.pipe2));
                this.arrPipes.get(this.arrPipes.size()-1).randomY();
            }else {
                this.arrPipes.add(new Pipe(this.arrPipes.get(i-sumpipe/2).getX(),this.arrPipes.get(i-sumpipe/2).getY()
                        +this.arrPipes.get(i-sumpipe/2).getHeight() + this.distance, 200*Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/1080, Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/2));

                this.arrPipes.get(this.arrPipes.size()-1).setBm(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pipe1));
            }
        }

    }

    private void initBird() {
        bird = new Bird();
        bird.setWidth(100*Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/1080);
        bird.setHeight(100*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/1920);
        bird.setX(100*Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/1080);
        bird.setY(Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-bird.getHeight()/2);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> ArrBms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrBms.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.bird1));
        ArrBms.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.bird2));
        bird.setArrBms(ArrBms);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);
        bird.draw(canvas);
        for (int i = 0; i < sumpipe; i++) {

            if (this.arrPipes.get(i).getX() < -arrPipes.get(i).getWidth()){
                this.arrPipes.get(i).setX(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH);
                if(i < sumpipe/2){
                    arrPipes.get(i).randomY();
                }else {
                    arrPipes.get(i).setY(this.arrPipes.get(i-sumpipe/2).getY()
                    +this.arrPipes.get(i-sumpipe/2).getHeight() + this.distance);
                }
            }
            this.arrPipes.get(i).draw(canvas);
        }

        handler.postDelayed(r, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            bird.setDrop(-15);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQmqj.png)

Comment: Java !== Javascript.

Comment: thank u . i posted a little quick